# How to add default value to function with generic

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a following function

`const run = <T extends Record<any, any>>(arg?: T = {}) => {}`

but i am getting the error

```
  '{}' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Record<any, any>'
```

I need to be able to pass any object and if i do not then function is called with empty object

Answer (score 1):

the issue come from `arg?: T = {}` where {} is not assignable to T that extends Record<any, any>

a solution can be to define a `Record<any, any>` variable before your function declaration and used it as default value for arg

```
const defaultValue: Record<any, any> = {};
const run = <T extends Record<any, any>>(arg: T = defaultValue) => {};
```

Answer (score 1):

not sure what you meant to do here
but i have something similer you can use.
the problem is T is generic, and the compiler can't guess the type of it.

```
const myCustomMapping: { [requestId: string]: { status: 
string, fulfilled: boolean} } = {
   '1234-1234-1234-1423': { status: 'OK', fulfilled: true}
```

}